# How to test mobile website on my PC/Laptop

Tags: html

I am building a website which detects the target browser whether it is mobile or pc browser. Based on the content it choose theme.
What I want to ask is. Is there any mobile browser which I can download in my pc to test my site instead of on phone many times?

Comment: F.e. Opera offers an Opera Mobile Emulator: http://www.opera.com/developer/mobile-emulator

Comment: I can't find any download link there

Comment: You’re right, the download links seem to be broken right now – it’s been a while since I last downloaded it. Maybe send the Opera guys an email and ask what’s up …

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could change the user agent to an user agent from a mobile browser. [Extension on Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg)

Comment: This is the best plugin to use for that tested a few yesterday

Answer (score 4):

You don't need any extensions, you can just change the User Agent manually on Chrome's Developer tools, just click on the settings Icon and then refresh the page (as you can see this page's look changes):

[image]

Comment: I cant find a setting like user agent. Even in advance settings. I am wondering how your browser have!

Comment: I have Chrome v26, I just pressed Control+shift+J, clicked on the gear icon and then on the `Overrides` option, which version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: @GunahGaar Under Tools > Developer Tools, then you click on the gear in the right bottom corner

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://bjango.com/mac/skalapreview/) is what I use normally. It is not exactly what you are looking for  I think but its worth the money!

Answer (score 0):

Stick with webkit browsers for mobile testing, sans Windows Phone.  Don't overlook the Android SDK's emulator and, if you're on a Mac, the iOS simulator, as you may come across rendering issues that don't exist in-browser.